# Restricting the Web service request itself gets resubmitted after 5 minutes

Tags: web-services, http, rest, timeout, submission

the web service request for one of our java rest service gets submitted again from the client/browser after ever 5 minutes in case when the service is taking longer to execute. 
Can we restrict this to get resubmitted once it has taken sufficiently longer.

Regards,

Vaibhav

Comment: I'm guessing the client/browser makes the request through JavaScript, yeah? In that case, you should show the code that makes the call, so we can help you restricting it to call the service only once.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly happened to me, only difference is mine is simple HTTP Post request and not web-service request.

Which application server you are using? Its upto application server to resubmit the request in case of Request Timeout.

You observed it right, the interval of double trigger is exact 5 minutes, that means your HTTP server is configured to timeout after 5 minutes, You need to set the timeout to -1 (infinite) or some sensible longer value so that the request won't get timed out and re-submit again.